# How to increase connection ServerSocket in dart

Tags: dart, sockets, networking, server, tcp

I tried to build a server with darts, but when it was built the number of max connections max 1015
can you go beyond that?

My specs Pc
amd ryzen 5500u 8gb ram

The [Code](https://nekobin.com/ciluyuhade) I made

Comment: There should not be any limits builtin in Dart so it is more likely a limitation set on the operating system you are running your server on. Since you have not specified what platform you are running this server on, I cannot be more precise in what you can try.

Comment: Also, I hope you are not spawning 1015 isolates here for your test since that would be rather unnecessary. ;)